# How to use SMIL Playlist file for VOD at RED5 Server

Tags: php, streaming, video-streaming, red5, smil

i want to stream vod using SMIL Playlist File at Red5 Server. how can i implement this at Red5 server. At wowza server the following link described how to config SMIL Playlist file

http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145-Stream-class-example-with-playlists-and-schedules-set-in-smil-file

i am using AWS S3 for vod. i have created bucket and gave full permission to everyone. And i am stream using RTMP coludfront . this is my following SMIL file

how can i do this in red5 like wowza.

Answer (score 0):

Have some experience with both servers and don't know of a playlist equivalent in Red5.

You'll have to code your own red5 rtmp application or use a webcam simulator like Fake Webcam on a computer that will broadcast a playlist of videos.

Answer (score 0):

since Wowza *is* red5, is should be possible.